# Error from google maps API when in an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a simple angular directive which adds google maps places searchbox to an input. See [this example on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox). I don't even need the map, just the search box.

The directive runs successfully (console print of the search box object is successful), but I get an error on the console after it runs, and the input doesn't work. The error in the console is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Just to be sure, I'm using another directive right beside it, which initialized a date picker using jquery-ui. That seems to work fine.

The HTML:

```
<html ng-app="events">      
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        Date:
        <input type="text" datetime-input="format" />
        <br>
        Location:
        <input type="text" location-input="format" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS:

```
var events = angular.module('events', []);

events.directive('locationInput', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(element);
        console.log(scope.searchBox);
    }

    return {
        link: link
    };
});

events.directive('datetimeInput', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).datepicker();
    }

    return {
        link: link
    };
});
```

See [the Plunkr I've created](http://plnkr.co/edit/7pPPLVtq0IKkCHMdsJDk?p=preview).

Why is there an error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this directive: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete ?

Comment: Thanks! That does work. I'd +1 your comment if I had enough credit.. But I would like to know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that element isn't in the proper format for the callback, you have to do `element[0]`. Afterwards, you will have to attach a listener.  Your code will look something like this:

```
scope.searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(element[0]);
google.maps.event.addListener(scope.searchBox,'places_changed',function(){
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    for(var i =0, place;place=places[i];i++){
        console.log(place.icon+':'+place.name+':'+ place.geometry.location);
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, apparently element[0] was what I was missing. Thanks! (even though we are 9 months since I asked the question)